# Prove that if $W$ is a subspace of $V$ vector space, and $(V\setminus W) \cup \{ 0\ $} is also a subspace of $V$, then $W=V$ or $W=\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$V$ is some vector space over a field $F$.

$W$ is subspace of $V$.

$(V\setminus W) \cup \{0\}$ is also a subspace of $V$ (that is all vectors in $V$ but not in $W$, and $0$ vector).

I need to prove that either $V=W$ or $W =\{0\}$ - just contains the zero vector and nothing more.

Supposing $V=W$ then $V=W$ and we are done, but if they are not equal how do I find that every vector in $W$ is the zero vector?

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! For more information about using MathJax visit https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $v \in V\setminus W $ and $0\neq w \in W$.
Then if $v+w \in W$, we get the contradiction $v+w-w\in W$.
So $v+w \in V\setminus W\cup \{0\}$ which is supposed to be a subspace. Hence the contradiction $v+w-v=w\in V\setminus W$.

That is too much of contradictions... and conclude the proof.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand the above answer:
If W=V then its trivial.
assume W≠V.

Take v∈V∖W and 0≠w∈W.

if v+w ∈W and W is a subspace then (v+w)−w ∈ W which means that v∈W.

```
which contradicts v∈V∖W{0} unless v=0.
```

if v+w ∈ V∖W∪{0} and V∖W∪{0} is a subspace then (v+w)-v ∈V∖W∪{0}. which means that w∈V∖W.

```
which contradicts w∈W, unless w=o.
```

thus any vector in W must be zero --> W = {0}.